# Rename Two files in the Same Folder

Tags: bash, rename, cp

Files

```
  events-number1.10a.pdf
```

Result

```
 events-number1.10a.docx.pdf
```

Ideal

```
 events-number1.10a.pdf   
 events-number1.10a.docx.pdf
```

Comment: What's your expected output ? 2nd or 3rd?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in  *.pdf
do
    new_file=$(echo "$file"  | sed -r 's/(.*)(\.pdf)/\1.docx\2/')
    mv $file $new_file
done
```

**Output:**

```
events-number1.index10a.docx.pdf 
events-number1.index10b.docx.pdf 
events-number1.index10c.docx.pdf 
events-number2.index10a.docx.pdf 
events-number2.index10b.docx.pdf 
events-number2.index10c.docx.pdf
```

If you want copy the file using `cp` command instead of `mv` command

```
cp $file $new_file
```

So your existing files won't change.

**Explanation :**
Passing all the log file to for loop ,then split the file name to your expected result for using `sed` command and stored in one variable . Then mv the old file to new file that mean your expected file .

Comment: Wow, while i am still watching tutorial. possible answer is ready!

Comment: Can you explian Wow, while i am still watching tutorial. possible answer is ready!
Can you explain a little bit ? I don't just want the answer and it is not the ideal result, which means I need to works on that with your explanation. By the way, It doesn't work on Mac

Comment: Both two inner lines can be joined in one by using bash parameter expansion techniques: `mv "${file}" "${file#log}main.gmt.log"`

Comment: @user3096996,Updated my answer .

Comment: @Jdamian,Your suggestion is wrong , "${file#log}main.gmt.log" this output add the `main.gmt.log` in end of the file like `events-number2.index10a.log` but the result is `events-number2.index10a.main.gmt.log`

Answer (score 0):

A simple rename command will do the job.

```
rename 's/(?=\.pdf$)/.docx/' *.pdf
```